# Fetching one value from mysql using mysqli fails

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to fetch a single value from mysql using mysqli but my code does not fetch the value for me.This is my code

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "my_journals";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$stock_type = 'vehicle_certificates';

$old_amount = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT amount FROM stock WHERE stock_type='."$stock_type".' limit 1'));

$newer_amount = $old_amount['amount'];
echo $newer_amount;

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

I get this error

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\wamp\www\journals_debug.php on line 16

What is causing my code not to work?.

Comment: Use prepared statements. A lot of your errors would automatically be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no quotes when the query goes to the db.

```
'SELECT amount FROM stock WHERE stock_type='."$stock_type".' limit 1'
```

Should be

```
'SELECT amount FROM stock WHERE stock_type="'.$stock_type.'" limit 1'
```

Currently when it arrives at the DB it is:

```
SELECT amount FROM stock WHERE stock_type=vehicle_certificates limit 1
```

which I think would is throwing a 1064 but you aren't seeing that because the return isn't checked.

You need the quotes encapsulated otherwise PHP processes them.

If that value weren't static this could open you to SQL injections. You should use prepared statements.

A third approach could be

```
"SELECT amount FROM stock WHERE stock_type='$stock_type' limit 1"
```

And as a prepared statement, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php, this could be something like:

```
$conn->prepare("SELECT amount FROM stock WHERE stock_type=? limit 1");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $stock_type);
$stmt->execute();
```

With the prepared approach you don't need to worry about quoting the input correctly. That is handled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

$results = mysqli_query..

then use this to get the error :

```
   if (!$result) {
     echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
   }
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp

Comment: I'd recommend linking to the `php.net` manual over `w3`, much more authoritative. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php